# Crosstable package on R: How to only show percentages?

Tags: r, crosstable

How do I only show percentages with the `crosstable()` function on R? I don't want the numbers to show on my example below.

Here's an example of my code:

```r
control <- crosstable(ce_merged, c(msgctrl1_emotion, msgctrl2_emotion, msgctrl3_emotion, msgctrl4_emotion, msgctrl5_emotion), by=condition, percent_digits=0) %>%
  as_flextable(keep_id=FALSE)
control
```

Example of output:

[image: EXAMPLE OF OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer without a reproducible example, but the key here is to use `percent_pattern` with only the percentage you are interested in (and some decoration text if needed).

```r
control <- crosstable(ce_merged, c(msgctrl1_emotion, msgctrl2_emotion), 
                      by=condition, percent_digits=0, 
                      percent_pattern="pct={p_row}") %>%
  as_flextable(keep_id=FALSE)
```

You can see more about this in the documentation: https://danchaltiel.github.io/crosstable/reference/crosstable.html#percent-pattern